# Trying to deploy Web Server Application

Tags: tomcat, port

Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use.
Can you tell me how to close the port?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to shutdown the application which is using this port. Maybe another instance of Tomcat is already running. You can verify this by just going to http://localhost:8080 in a webbrowser. If this is true, you'll need to shutdown it first before starting it. Or if your intent is to have two Tomcats simultaneous running, you'll need to give one of both a different port in the [HTTP connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) in `server.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running JBoss or some other webserver? If so try shutting it down to free port 8080.
To shutdown these ports, stop the services that are using them.

You can also run the following in command line to determine the process using port 8080.

netstat -o